# Rails.env vs RAILS_ENV

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see both in examples when checking what env one is running in.  What's preferred?  Are they, for all intents and purposes equal?

Answer (score 385, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html#method-c-env), `#Rails.env` wraps `RAILS_ENV`:

```
    # File vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb, line 55
     def env
       @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(RAILS_ENV)
     end
```

But, look at specifically *how* it's wrapped, using `ActiveSupport::StringInquirer`:

> Wrapping a string in this class gives
>   you a prettier way to test for
>   equality. The value returned by
>   Rails.env  is wrapped in a
>   StringInquirer  object so instead of
>   calling this:
>
> ```
> Rails.env == "production"
> ```
>
> you can call this:
>
> ```
> Rails.env.production?
> ```

So they aren't *exactly* equivalent, but they're fairly close.  I haven't used Rails much yet, but I'd say `#Rails.env` is certainly the more visually attractive option due to using `StringInquirer`.

Comment: nice explanation, thx!  I'm also trying to find where RAILS_ENV is defined?  Any idea??

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Rails.env` is the new standard as `RAILS_ENV` is being deprecated.

Comment: Ryan, on a command line, you can't use Rails.env. so if it's deprecating soon, then what would you use on the CLI?

Comment: Using Rails.env.production? secures you against typos actually changing the environment like this: RAILS_ENV = "production". Notice the missed = sign.

Comment: All this ridiculous complexity just so you can use a question mark?

Answer (score 36):

`ENV['RAILS_ENV']` is now **deprecated**.

You should use `Rails.env` which is clearly much nicer.

Answer (score 29):

Before Rails 2.x the preferred way to get the current environment was using the `RAILS_ENV` constant. Likewise, you can use `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` to get the current logger or `RAILS_ROOT` to get the path to the root folder.

Starting from Rails 2.x, Rails introduced the `Rails` module with some special methods:

- Rails.root
- Rails.env
- Rails.logger

This isn't just a cosmetic change. The Rails module offers capabilities not available using the standard constants such as `StringInquirer` support.
There are also some slight differences. `Rails.root` doesn't return a simple `String` buth a `Path` instance.

Anyway, the preferred way is using the `Rails` module. Constants are deprecated in Rails 3 and will be removed in a future release, perhaps Rails 3.1.

Comment: FYI, from what was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411708/rails-env-undefined-in-rails-2), it sounds like those methods were introduced in Rails 2.3, not 2.0.

Comment: We're using 2.1.2 on a project.  `Rails.env` works without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Strange behaviour while debugging my app:
require "active_support/notifications"
(rdb:1) p ENV['RAILS_ENV']
"test"
(rdb:1) p Rails.env
"development"

I would say that you should stick to one or another (and preferably Rails.env)

Answer (score 2):

Update: in Rails 3.0.9: 
env method defined in railties/lib/rails.rb