# RAILS_ENV vs Rails.env? And Why the values are different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment, environment-variables

I have already read this question : [Rails.env vs RAILS_ENV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715035/rails-env-vs-rails-env)

I have added rails-dev-boost plugin (http://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost) and it internally uses Rails.env.development? to check and bypass its scripts if its not development. This is generally okay.

But I also use Spork Testunit (http://github.com/timcharper/spork-testunit/)to fire up a test server to quickly run tests. But this causes problem and loads up rails-dev-boost while running the tests. I checked within the rails-dev-boost plugin's init.rb and it says :

```
Rails.env.development? # = true
RAILS_ENV # = "test"
```

Why are these values different? Is there any other things that are settings these values different? Any ideas?

Comment: and `Rails.env` say what ? You use rails 3 or 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

In the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails.html#method-c-env):

```
def env
   @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```