# Rails.env undefined in Rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rubygems, environment, undefined

I have an older application running Ruby on Rails 2.2, and I'm having trouble getting a gem to work because it can't find the current environment with `Rails.env`:

```
$ script/console
>> Rails.env
NoMethodError: undefined method `env' for Rails:Module
from (irb):1
```

The gem is set up to use `Rails.env` when `Rails` is defined, and `RAILS_ENV` when it's not. But I seem to have a `Rails` object without an `env` method (even though I read that method was added in Rails 2). Any idea what's going on?

Comment: I don't have 2.2 installed (2.3.8 has that method), but you can look @ what methods are available by running this in the console: `puts Rails.methods.sort`.

Comment: There are 138 methods listed, but no `env`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Rails` module has always been in rails. It is not new in 3, so checking to see if it's defined is the wrong way to go about things. The correct way to determine if you can use `Rails.env` is to do `Rails.respond_to? :env`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll pass that along to the gem maintainer. In the meantime, what makes most sense as a workaround? Is there any harm in defining `Rails.env` to be `RAILS_ENV`?

Comment: @jrdioko For 2.x compatability you could do that, but it's not a good idea to always just use `RAILS_ENV` as it is deprecated in 3.

Comment: `Rails.method_defined?(:env)` returns false even on Rails 3.

Comment: I think it should be `Rails.respond_to?(:env)`.

Answer (score 4):

`Rails.env` was introduced in Rails 2.3. You probably want to upgrade to Rails 2.3 if possible.

Otherwise, try this in a `config/initializers/rails_env.rb`:

```
require 'active_support/string_inquirer'
def Rails.env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But no `ActiveSupport::StringInquirer` on my system. I suppose I could make it a straight string?

Comment: You can try that, depends on the gem you are using. If it does `Rails.env.production?` then you need the StringInquirer. In that case, you can backport it: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb