# Calling Mixpanel API only in production Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment

I am currently using mixpanel with the default ['mixpanel' gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mixpanel/0.8.1/frames) for analytics and have some calls set up in my controllers.  I would like those calls to only run in the production environment.  Is the best way to do this something like this for every call:

```
@mixpanel.track_event("Job Accepted", {:user=> current_user.id}) if RAILS_ENV == 'production'
```

Seems like overkill, but I'm struggling to think of a better solution.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the right idea.  Though you might want to use:

```
Rails.env.production?
```

instead.  ( See [Rails.env vs RAILS_ENV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715035/rails-env-vs-rails-env) )

Answer (score 5):

Older question, but here is my method. Replace Mixpanel's default consumer(which sends to their API) with something more useful in testing. In our case, we just log out. This is in an initializer like mixpanel.rb.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  MIXPANEL = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(ENV['MIXPANEL_TOKEN'])
else
  MIXPANEL = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(ENV['MIXPANEL_TOKEN']) do |type, message|
     Rails.logger.debug("Mixpanel Request: #{type}, #{message}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for, found it in the Gem's wiki:

https://github.com/zevarito/mixpanel/wiki/Disable-Mixpanel-tracking-in-desired-environments-with-Rails

Comment: There's no reason to memoize/cache the value of Rails.env.production? It's just comparing strings under the covers.

Comment: You're totally right! Thanks for the correction, I have updated the answer.