# Rails - How do I check developer mode or production mode in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am doing a project in rails, I would like to know How do I check whether I am running in developer mode  or  production mode in code ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715035/rails-env-vs-rails-env

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
Rails.env == "production"

Rails.env == "development"
```

As mentioned by @xoebus, this is far better:

```
Rails.env.production?

Rails.env.development?
```