# Ruby on Rails - using modules from a different directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, directory, require

This is a very basic question, but I can't find exactly the answer I need.

I have the following code in trunk/app/models/parsers/my_file.rb in my dev environment:

```
def initialize
  ...
  @logger = Utils::SingletonLogger.get_logger
  @logger.debug("Instantiating my_file object")
end
```

It runs fine.

But when I deploy it to the test environment (all code should be identical, but I'm not sure where to start looking for differences if there are any), Rails complains that it can't find Parsers::MyFile::Utils.  The Utils module I want to use is in app/lib/my_utils.rb. This makes me think that Rails is creating some sort of namespace for the code in the parsers sub-directory, and only looking there for the Utils module, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work for me.  Is there some main, application level prefix I can use to specify to look outside of the current directory structure?

I've tried adding `require 'my_utils'` and `require_relative '../../../lib/my_utils.rb'`.  The former can't find the file, the latter just throws the same error as when I don't have any require at all.  I'm not sure if I should have to require this or not.

In any case, I clearly don't quite understand how to refer to code in modules in a different directory, I don't understand when/why rails needs an explicit path at some times/environments but not others, and I don't know how to make Rails look outside of the current file for code.  Any help with any of these would be appreciated.

Oh, I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, and rails 3.2.1.

Edit:  It just started working, without any changes to the application.rb or environment files.  It doesn't even have a require in the current version.  Is there any obvious reason for it not to work at first, then to work after another server restart?  (I'm pretty sure I restarted it after the code went in - I don't think I just forgot to do that before.)

Anyway, thanks for your help - I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have different gems in your Gemfile for dev vs. test environment?

Comment: Nope, the local gemfile and the test gemfile look identical.

Comment: I was referring to the `:development` vs. `:test` environments _within_ the Gemfile.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  The only environment-specific thing I see in the Gemfile is a comment that a group of asset gems is not required in production.  I guess that if the test environment thinks it's production, that could make a difference.  Is there a good way to test that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476832/rails-how-do-i-check-developer-mode-or-production-mode-in-code

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add directories you want to include in application.rb. Might want to make sure in your application.rb or test.rb config files you have this autoload_paths in there, yours might be specific to your development.rb file.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/)
```