# Rails.env in ruby scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715035/rails-env-vs-rails-env) is a discussion of using `Rails.env` instead of `RAILS_ENV`, since it's being depricated.
I don't quite understand what to do in standalone scripts like `delayed_job`, where you specifically pass in the `RAILS_ENV`:

```
RAILS_ENV=test script/delayed_job start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest [Configuring Rails Applications Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-environment-settings) says that:

> `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` defines the Rails environment (production, development, test, and so on) that Rails will run under.

So *setting* the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable to choose the environment is fine but you're supposed to look at `Rails.env` to *get* the current environment.

If you look at the [`Rails.env` implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3cbc1bd395c4f6699dd4d8384b85c0d214a12c81/railties/lib/rails.rb#L81):

```
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

you'll also notice that it looks at the `RACK_ENV` environment variable as well as `RAILS_ENV`. Also note the [StringInquirer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/StringInquirer.html) wrapper so that you can say `Rails.env.production?` instead of `(ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development') == 'production'`.