# How to get the current Rack environment in Rake?

Tags: ruby, rake, rack

Is there a way to get information about the current Rack environment in Rake? For example, how can I tell whether Rack is running in `development` or `production` mode?

I understand that Rake is not Rack-aware. I'm trying to avoid replicating code in nearly-identical Rake tasks between production and dev environments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715035/rails-env-vs-rails-env

Comment: @ted, that link is about usage of rack environment within Rails, and doesn't mention anything about rake. How does it apply?

Comment: Please display those different Rake tasks. Maybe we can help if we see some code.

Comment: There is nothing special about the tasks. Simplest case: I want to connect to different databases depending on whether I'm in dev or production.

Answer (score 7):

Question is old but never fetched the best practice answer or a satisfying answer at all.

The real question is: **How to go sure which environment is used in a Rake task in order to load the correct configuration / hitting into correct if-conditions.**

> Note: As Rake doesn't give much about Rack (Rake is not using HTTP) to
>   rely on the RACK_ENV is basically wrong but common and handy if a Rake
>   task loads your main Sinatra application (the RACK_ENV is required to let 
>   Sinatras development? / test? / production? being set correctly).

The answer: **Set the environment with each Rake task call.**

Command line call:

```
/usr/bin/rake namespace:task_name RACK_ENV=production
```

Cronjob call (in crontab):

```
cd /into/your/app/root && /usr/bin/rake namespace:task_name RACK_ENV=production --silent
```

> Note: To specify the path of the Rake bin is not necessary if you have it in your global system variables. Your path might differs from mine used in the examples, check on Unix systems with: whereis rake

You can check the `RACK_ENV` in your tasks via:

```
puts ENV["RACK_ENV"]
```

Comment: I usually have an `:environment` task that all other tasks depend on. Within that I always set default values any other task would need. So I'd go further and suggest defining `ENV['RACK_ENV'] ||= 'development'` either at the top of the Makefile or inside of an `:environment` task.

Answer (score 6):

As other environment variable, you can retrieve it using:

```
ENV['RACK_ENV']
```

Considering it's a Sinatra application, and that you've set the environment into `config/environment.rb`, you can add the following to your `Rakefile`:

```
task :environment do
  require File.expand_path('config/environment', File.dirname(__FILE__))
end

task :your_task => :environment do
  # task
end
```

Then, you can retrieve the environment (depending how you set it up in your `environment.rb`) with `ENV['RACK_ENV']` or `Sinatra::Application.environment`.

Considering there isn't a `config/environment.rb` config file, only the application file, for instance `hello_world.rb`, the following works:

hello_world.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :environment, :production

get '/' do
  'Hello World'
end
```

Rakefile:

```
task :environment do
  require File.expand_path('hello_world', File.dirname(__FILE__)) # your Sinatra app
end

task :your_task => :environment do
  puts Sinatra::Application.environment
end
```

When doing `rake your_task` you should obtain:

```
> rake your_task
production
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Here's a simple Rakefile to illustrate:
`task :test_rack_env do
  puts ENV['RACK_ENV']
end`

Prints a blank line.

Comment: Where do you set the Rack environment to `production` or `development`?

Comment: I'm using Sinatra, so it sets the environment.

Comment: @ArmanH I've updated my answer. Hope it will help you this time.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded answer; however, there is no config file in a Sinatra app, and the environment is not being set through it. Instead, Sinatra uses `set :environment, :production`.

Comment: @ArmanH I've updated my answer considering you just have one Sinatra app where you have set up the environment.

Answer (score 3):

*After 2.5 years, I want to share what I've found to be the best solution.*

---

Create a `.env` file in the root folder of the application, and add a flag specifying the application environment:

```
ENVIRONMENT=development
```

Then use Brandon Keepers' [**`dotenv`**](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem to load all environment variables from this file. Now you can use any environment variables specified in `.env` within Rake tasks.

Rake will rely on the explicit value set in `.env`, so you must create separate `.env` files for each environment you plan on using (e.g. *dev*, *test*, *staging*, *production*, etc).

Sample `Rakefile`:

```
require 'dotenv/tasks'

task :default => :help

desc 'Show this help menu'
task :help do
    puts "Available rake tasks:"
    system('rake --tasks')
end

# Will run in any environment
desc 'Demo task'
task :demo_task => :dotenv do
    puts "Running demo task in '#{ENV['ENVIRONMENT']}' mode"
end

# Will only run if ENVIRONMENT value in .env file is set to 'production'
desc 'Production-only task'
task :production_task => :dotenv do
    if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'production'
        puts "Running 'Production-only' task"
    else
        puts "Won't run, because the environment is not set to PRODUCTION!"
    end
end

# Will only run if ENVIRONMENT value in .env file is set to 'development'
desc 'Development-only task'
task :dev_task => :dotenv do
    if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'development'
        puts "Running 'Development-only' task"
    else
        puts "Won't run, because the environment is not set to DEVELOPMENT!"
    end
end
```

If you want to use the environment variables within your Rack or Sinatra app (which you probably do), add the following to the application's config or bootstrap block:

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I'm looking for! Just to clarify, to use different `.env` files for different environments, do you use [avdi's approach](http://devblog.avdi.org/2014/01/17/dotenv-for-multiple-environments/) or some other mechanism for rake to pick up env vars in different `.env` files?

Comment: To test production settings locally, I have a file called `.env.production`, which I switch out with `.env` while running tests (renaming the local env file to `.env.local` while testing).