# How to make a data structure available across an entire rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have the following `application_helper.rb` method:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def grades_k_5
    [
      ['',],
      ['Preschool', -1],
      ['Kindergarten', 0],
      ['First grade', 1],
      ['Second grade', 2],
      ['Third grade', 3],
      ['Fourth grade', 4],
      ['Fifth grade', 5],
    ]
  end
```

Up until now, I've only used it in views (to populate a dropdown selector), but now I'd also like to use it in one of my models. How can I take that array and put it somewhere so that I can reference it from this helper method, and also another method that I'd include in my model? Ultimately, what I'm looking for is one place (DRY) to change this if I ever need to modify the structure rather than having to go to multiple methods.

Comment: down the road you may find it makes more sense to just create a database table that has these values and make it a first class model object, I am guessing you save those values into other models already?

Comment: Interesting. I'm relatively new to all this, and it wouldn't have occurred to me to put something this small and nearly completely static into its own table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many options exist for static data like this. The simplest way is a class method.

```
class StaticData
  def self.grades_k_5
    [
      ['',],
      ['Preschool', -1],
      ['Kindergarten', 0],
      ['First grade', 1],
      ['Second grade', 2],
      ['Third grade', 3],
      ['Fourth grade', 4],
      ['Fifth grade', 5],
    ]
  end
end

# then 
StaticData.grades_k_5
```

You can also put it into a YAML file and have a piece of logic that parses that file and gives you the data. But it's a bit more complicated and probably not needed in your case.

Comment: A class method is the right way to go.  BTW this looks like it would be better stored as a hash than an array.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: looks to me that it's an array, because it's fed directly to `options_for_select`. A hash should work equally well, though.

Comment: Why the class method instead of constant? Class method will create a new array every time it is called.

Comment: @BroiSatse: uniform access. More flexible. Later you might want to read the data from file. No need to touch 350 usages of the constant across the codebase. Memoize if temp objects concern you.

Comment: @BroiSatse: long long time ago current rails env was available at `RAILS_ENV`. It has since been [deprecated in favor of `Rails.env`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715035/rails-env-vs-rails-env). Its current implementation contains `@_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")`. And you didn't even knew/noticed. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah, i assumed it was for looking things up.  never mind then :)

Comment: Sadly, many of these comments are way over my head. That said, the reason I picked an array rather than a hash is that I'm still walking in Michael Hartl's footsteps on this one. It's how he handles this sort of thing in the Rails Tutorial.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Well, I am a developer for 3 years, so never used it as a constant. `And you didn't even knew/noticed.` - thank you for that, I will keep it in mind the next time I'll ask any question. Was my question offensive?

Comment: @BroiSatse: sorry, I didn't mean it as an insult. :) My point was, if it's a method, you're abstracted from its implementation. It can change without affecting you. Whereas with a constant, you are very much tied to the fact that it is a constant.

Comment: @BroiSatse: now answer honestly, though: _do_ you notice when something like `Rails.env` changes implementation without breaking your code? Was my assumption not accurate?

Comment: @BroiSatse: " I am a developer for 3 years" - well, it was deprecated before that. :)